# Removing scrollbar from <object> Embed

Tags: html, css

Currently I am using object to embed a adsense ad in a webpage

```
<object data="frontpage_blogrool_center_top_728x90" type="text/html" width="732" height="95" ></object>
```

I made the object larger than the original so that the scrollbar will not appear on the webpage but it still appears in IE8. Is there anyway to remove it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Add `style="overflow:hidden; width: 732px; height: 95px"`  to the element:

```
<object data="frontpage_blogrool_center_top_728x90" 
        type="text/html" width="732" height="95"
        style="overflow:hidden; width: 732px; height: 95px"></object>
```

Comment: @BlindingDawn: I've updated my answer with something that might work.

Comment: Thanks for pointing me in the right direction. The above code works but I had to adjust the size a little more to get it to fit

Answer (score 8):

You must add to the **parent** of the `<object />` element's css, `overflow: hidden;`

Example:

```
<body style="overflow:hidden;">
    <object ...>
    </object>
</body>
```

Comment: Awesome!  The accepted answer, combined with this, was exactly what I was looking for.

Answer (score 3):

Give the `<object>` a `min-height: 101%` or more!

Example:

```
object {
  min-width: 100%;
  min-height: 101%; //not 100% but more than 101
}
```

Comment: This was the only thing that worked for me, I put it in my CSS-file and it worked at once. Even when i scroll zoom in and out. Magic thanks. :)

Answer (score 0):

I solved my similar problem (embedding a complex SVG with all his JS and style stuff) just by adding a position: fixed to the body tag of the HTML content I wanted to embed. Though I can use a width:100% to keep my dimensions everywhere.

Comment: I am trying for something similar, and finding that a SVG with JS that resizes itself, doesn't work very well inside an '<object>' tag.  This is a particular problem with IE11, Firefox works fine.  The scrollbars with overflow:scroll don't resize themselves correctly so that (a) the whole graphic is rendered, and (b) the scrollbars work to access all regions of the graphic.  I feel kind of stuck on IE being unable to resize / render the graphic inside an object.

Answer (score -2):

Can be achieved with

```
display: flex;
```